# Stanford CoreNLP can not detect sentence with numbering

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a word document with numbering like 1.  ,2.  etc.
I want to extract sentences from the document.
I use Stanford CoreNLP 4.0.0 and stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar
Normal extraction of sentences retrieve numbers as different sentence.
Suppose document has

1. Abcd efgh....
2. Ijkl mnop....

Sentence extraction gets 1 as a sentence and Abcd efgh as another sentence.

Similarly 2 as a sentence and Ijkl mnop as another sentence.

I try with boundariesToDiscard properties with different patterns but get same result and also get wrong entity mentions in this case.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. I just set the following property

```
props.setProperty("ssplit.eolonly", "true");
```